# Using yum versionlock to only allow patch updates?

Tags: yum

I am running RHEL7.6 and I need to lock my bind install to 9.11.

Currently, we are at 9.11.4, and I would like to take any additional patches for 9.11 that are released.

I found the yum versionlock plugin, but after what I thought would just lock it to major.minor, it appears to lock the entire package:

```
# yum versionlock bind-9.11.*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Adding versionlock on: 32:bind-9.11.4-9.P2.el7
versionlock added: 1

# yum versionlock
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
32:bind-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.*
versionlock list done
```

This looks like it's locked to the installed version.

Additionally, I tried the following

```
#yum versionlock bind-9.11
#yum versionlock bind-9.*
#yum versionlock bind-9
```

they all resulted in `versionlock added: 0`.

Am I using the right tool here?   Is this even possible (with off the shelf tools, not me rewriting yum, poorly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't do what you want to accomplish. It was meant to freeze the package in [the current installed version](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq.html). What you are looking for is the equivalent of apt-pinning (despite descriptions of the contrary, yum's versionlock actually provides the equivalent of apt-hold, apt-preferences is much more powerful and versatile). Sadly, it seems that yum doesn't have this functionality in the base package, nor by plugin.

Comment: sigh, I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the info though!  I'll accept your answer in 24hrs, hoping some bright spark comes up with a wacky idea to try between now and then.